# Mysql error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create some tables on phpMyAdmin, but when I use the code below I am getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(32) NOT NULL,
```

`activated` enum(`0`,`1`) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) E' at line 8

Here is my code:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sign_up_date` date(32) NOT NULL,
  `activated` enum(`0`,`1`) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=1atin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: change date(32) to date

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try following code. I have resolved your mistakes in code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
      `activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

[***DATE data type***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) takes no length

```
`sign_up_date` DATE NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`0`,`1`) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=1atin1' at line 9

Comment: @Theoko enum('0','1') don't use backticks in here use single quotes

Comment: I solved it. Bhumi Shah made some changes to my code. You are right, I should use single quotes.